# Customizing radio button grouping

Tags: html, radio-button

I have a scenario where I need to rank three options as high, medium or low. I have three radio buttons with values high, medium and low for each option. The selections need to be mutually exclusive.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/J7hVs/)**

**HTML**

```
<label>Option : 1</label>
<input name="high" type="radio" value="H"> High
<input name="medium" type="radio" value="M"> Medium
<input name="low" type="radio" value="L"> Low

<br/>
<label>Option : 2</label>
<input name="high" type="radio" value="H"> High
<input name="medium" type="radio" value="M"> Medium
<input name="low" type="radio" value="L"> Low
<br/>

<label>Option : 3</label>
<input name="high" type="radio" value="H"> High
<input name="medium" type="radio" value="M"> Medium
<input name="low" type="radio" value="L"> Low
```

By naming the radion buttons this way, I could achieve avoiding a multiple `high` selections. But, this leads to allowing all of them to be selected for a single option as well because each option has radio buttons named differently.

I know this can be achieved with some JQuery validation. But, need to know if is there any other way to do this with HTML itself.

Thanks.

Comment: multiple selection of same choice shouldnt be made!!?? in the sense only 1 high 1 medium and 1 low allowed?

Comment: @GreenWizard You understood it right.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly this should be the right way.

```
<label>Option : 1</label>
<input name="option1" type="radio" value="H"> High
<input name="option1" type="radio" value="M"> Medium
<input name="option1" type="radio" value="L"> Low

<br/>
<label>Option : 2</label>
<input name="option2" type="radio" value="H"> High
<input name="option2" type="radio" value="M"> Medium
<input name="option2" type="radio" value="L"> Low
<br/>

<label>Option : 3</label>
<input name="option3" type="radio" value="H"> High
<input name="option3" type="radio" value="M"> Medium
<input name="option3" type="radio" value="L"> Low
```

Comment: NO, you didn't. This would allow all the three options to be selected as high.